# How to modify an Akka HttpResponse?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am using Akka and I want to modify the entity of a `HttpResponse`. In particular, I want to modify the `body` or `header` of the particular `HttpResponse`. Since `HttpResponse` is a final class, I cannot modify it, but copying and setting a slightly modified `body` would be sufficient.

Here's my code:

```
val handler = Source.single(context.request)
        .via(flow)
        .runWith(Sink.head)
        .flatMap { r =>
          logger.info(s"Status code: ${r.status}.")
          val copyR = r.copy(status = r.status, headers = r.headers, entity = ???, protocol = r.protocol)
          context.complete(copyR)
        }
```

Is there an elegant way to parse the `entity` and modify certain elements of the DOM?

Comment: What do you mean by DOM ? `HttpResponse` is just stream of  bytes.

Comment: For example, I would like to add or remove links in `HttpResponse`.

Comment: Long story, but in short you need to unmarshal response to something that understands HTML/XML, modify it and then marshal back to binary. Take a look at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.11/scala/http/common/marshalling.html For HTML parsing I recommend JSoup. Akka-Http doesn't provide functionality to parse HTML.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for your help!